# "server unavailable" error when trying to authenticate user on Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

I'm getting a server unavailable error whenever I try to authenticate user on colab:

My code is simply

```
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
```

And I'm getting a

```
WARNING:google.auth.compute_engine._metadata:
Compute Engine Metadata server unavailable on attempt 1 of 3. 
Reason: [Errno 115] Operation now in progress
```

I wonder if Google has changed anything

Comment: Same problem... Google!!! Don't break on me now!!!

Comment: They have just posted the issue on Github

https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/3078